# MySQL select given number of rows and always select all rows within the same day

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

I want to do a MySQL Query which selects a given number of Rows from a single table from a given offset like

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE timestamp < '2011-11-04 09:01:05' 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC 
LIMIT 100
```

My problem is that i always want all rows within a day if one row of a day will be  included in the result.
It would be no problem to have a result with e.g. 102 rows instead of 100

Can i realize this with a single SQL statement?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you saying you want the LIMIT to stay at 100 if more than one day is represented in the results, but you want no LIMIT if all the results occur in the same day?

Comment: Hard to understand. Can you provide sample input and expected output?

Comment: The LIMIT has to be removed for this, for sure. I just want to get approx 100 results, but always want to get full days. So, if the last row is on a given day and the next row would be at that day too, I want to include this row in my result as well. Even if that would mean that I'd get 101 rows...

Comment: I think I got it. I've revised my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work on my system:

```
SELECT UserID, Created
FROM some_user
WHERE Created < '2011-11-04 09:10:11'
AND Created >= (
    SELECT DATE(Created) -- note: DATE() strips out the time portion from datetime
    FROM some_user
    WHERE Created < '2011-11-04 09:10:11'
    ORDER BY Created DESC
    LIMIT 99, 1 -- note: counting starts from 0 so LIMIT 99, 1 returns 100th row
)
ORDER BY Created DESC
-- 0 rows affected, 102 rows found. Duration for 1 query: 0.047 sec.
```

There might be a faster alternative.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you're intrested in retrievieng 100 rows, + any rows that are on the same day as ones already retrieved. You can do this using a subquery:

```
SELECT table.* 
FROM table, (
        SELECT DISTINCT day 
        FROM (
            SELECT TO_DAYS(timestamp) day 
            FROM table 
            WHERE timestamp < :? 
            LIMIT 100
            )
    ) days
WHERE TO_DAYS(table.timestamp) = days.day 
ORDER BY timestamp
```

Comment: I just tested this and it seems to select all rows from 100 days

Answer (score 0):

Exclude the time part in the query and remove the LIMIT.

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE timestamp < '2011-11-04 00:00:00' 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Comment: That would just return all items in the timerange. I just want to get approximately 100 results. I am well aware of the fact that I have to remove the LIMIT for that. I just don't see an easy, performant way to get approx 100 rows and don't cut any day off.